# Selecting some dimensions from a multi-dimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, matrix, numpy

I have a 4-D array, and I need to process all 1-D vectors from this array along a given dimension. This works well:

```py
    def myfun(arr4d,selected_dim):  # selected_dim can only be 2 or 3
        print arr4d.shape   # (2, 5, 10, 10)
        for i in xrange(arr4d.shape[0]):
            for j in xrange(arr4d.shape[1]):
                for k in xrange(arr4d.shape[selected_dim]):
                    if selected_dim==2:
                        arr=arr4d[i,j,k,:]
                    elif selected_dim==3:
                        arr=arr4d[i,j,:,k]
                    do_something(arr)  # arr is 1-D and has 10 items
```

...but I believe there is some way to avoid the nested "if" part, and maybe also be more efficient? Like creating other views of this array before the loops and then iterating through these views?

Comment: Do you mean the nested for loops being something you want to avoid? I only see one simple if...elif construct.

Comment: I mean avoid nested `if` and, optionally, avoid three `for`. Per @BiRico 's answer, `numpy.rollaxis` is one way to get rid of the "variable dimension" problem which troubled me.

Answer (score 3):

One common way to handle this is to use `np.rollaxis`:

```
def myfun(arr4d, selected_dim):  # selected_dim can only be 2 or 3
    arr4d = np.rollaxis(arr4d, selected_dim)
    print arr4d.shape   # (10, 2, 5, 10)
    for i in xrange(arr4d.shape[1]):
        for j in xrange(arr4d.shape[2]):
            for k in xrange(arr4d.shape[0]):
                arr=arr4d[k, i, j, :]
                do_something(arr)  # arr is 1-D and has 10 items
```

Note that `np.rollaxis` should return a view so it doesn't actually copy the array.

Comment: Thanks! Would it be possible to use `np.take` with the appropriate `axis`, and probably other arguments, to achieve similar effect? I was not able to do it, but it looks like `take` could be useful as well.